# Pulling information from Magento into wordpress?

Tags: php, database

I'm currently developing a wordpress theme for a site which has a shop running magento on the same server. I would really like to pull information from Magento into wordpress, such as a list of products, or product information.

Can anyone suggest a method for this, and/or a good tutorial. All of the information I've found assumes that Wordpress is someone running inside a Magento install. However these sites operate separately, and I would like to do this without plug-ins if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Magento and WordPress are different things. WordPress is a Content Management System (CMS) that allows you to create Pages/posts.

Magento is an e-commerce platform that allows you to sell products. There are plenty of e-commerce plugins for WordPress that you can install, and then import your Magento products into the database for that particular plugin.

I can't say how, since whatever plugin you choose will have different instructions. The most popular e-commerce plugin for WordPress is WooCommerce and then you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart2cart-magento-to-woocommerce-migration/ to migrate your data.

If you want to simply integrate Magento with WordPress so that you can utilize the products from magento in WordPress side-by-side then yes it's probably possible. https://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/ you can checkout this plugin to help you do that.

Or one another way you can also use any Magento products csv export extension with a WooCommerce CSV products import Extension.